# Does it have to be a coding question?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions, recommendation-questions

I want to ask about some good books to pick up for VBA and Solver noobs. Is VBA-Excel the appropriate tag?

OK, OK, I get it doesn't ask the question.

Comment: Yes. It does have to be a coding question.

Comment: [This might be of interest to you anyway.](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books)

Comment: Why can't people who have these questions in mind be bothered to check the help center instead of posting what HAS to have been asked or answered already?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Product recommendations are off topic on SO.